# How to Parse JSON Array Response when using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to get all string on https://animechan.vercel.app/api/available/anime but suddenly i can't get it, anyone would help me?
heres my code:

```js
axios.get('https://animechan.vercel.app/api/available/anime')
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Source of Anime Qoutes: \n\n\n" + JSON.parse(response.data));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: _"suddenly"_ suggests that it had worked at least once. What have you changed since then? Any errors? Hit the rate limit? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios automagically deserializes the response body from JSON to a Javascript object, assuming the response's content type is `application/json` or you tell Axios to do so regardless. See the documentation at

https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

All you should need is:

```js
var axios = require("axios");

axios.get( 'https://animechan.vercel.app/api/available/anime' )
.then( response => {
  console.log(`Source of Anime Qoutes:`);
  console.log( response.data.join('\n') );
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```